# How to build transaction payload for signed EIP-1559 transaction

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I am trying to construct the raw transaction data based on a signed EIP-1559 transaction according to the [EIP-1559 spec](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1559). However, it is not matching the value returned by web3py when signing a transaction. Below is a script I used to recreate the issue.

compute_raw_tx.py:

```
from web3 import Web3
import rlp    

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(NODE_URL))

tx = {
    'from': PUBLIC_KEY,
    'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(PUBLIC_KEY),
    'to': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    'value': Web3.toWei(0.01, 'ether'),
    'chainId': 5,
    'gas': 50000,
    'maxFeePerGas': Web3.toWei(500, 'gwei'),
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': Web3.toWei(200, 'gwei'),
    'data': '0x0'
}

signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY)

print(signed_tx)

encoded = rlp.encode([
    hex(tx['chainId']),
    hex(tx['nonce']),
    hex(tx['maxPriorityFeePerGas']),
    hex(tx['maxFeePerGas']),
    hex(tx['gas']),
    tx['to'],
    hex(tx['value']),
    tx['data'],
    [],
    hex(signed_tx['v']),
    hex(signed_tx['r']),
    hex(signed_tx['s'])
])

print(f'0x02{encoded.hex()}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/153644/manually-rlp-encoding-an-eth-tx-gives-an-incorrect-result), I didn't quite have the correct types for all the values. Here is the working solution:

```
encoded = rlp.encode([
        tx['chainId'],
        tx['nonce'],
        tx['maxPriorityFeePerGas'],
        tx['maxFeePerGas'],
        tx['gas'],
        to_bytes(hexstr=tx["to"]),
        tx['value'],
        HexBytes(tx['data']),
        [],
        signed_tx['v'],
        HexBytes(signed_tx['r']),
        HexBytes(signed_tx['s'])
    ])

    reconstructed_raw_transaction = f'0x02{encoded.hex()}'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to this function should be the "private_key". Try this out

```
import web3
import rlp

NODE_URL = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_API_KEY'
PUBLIC_KEY = '0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
PRIVATE_KEY = '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890'

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(NODE_URL))

tx = {
    'from': PUBLIC_KEY,
    'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(PUBLIC_KEY),
    'to': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    'value': Web3.toWei(0.01, 'ether'),
    'chainId': 5,
    'gas': 50000,
    'maxFeePerGas': Web3.toWei(500, 'gwei'),
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': Web3.toWei(200, 'gwei'),
    'data': '0x0'
}

signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(PRIVATE_KEY, tx)

print(signed_tx)

encoded = rlp.encode([
    hex(tx['chainId']),
    hex(tx['nonce']),
    hex(tx['maxPriorityFeePerGas']),
    hex(tx['maxFeePerGas']),
    hex(tx['gas']),
    tx['to'],
    hex(tx['value']),
    tx['data'],
    [],
    hex(signed_tx['v']),
    hex(signed_tx['r']),
    hex(signed_tx['s'])
])

print(f'0x02{encoded.hex()}')
```

Comment: Getting the following error:

`TypeError: transaction_dict must be dict-like, got '<PRIVATE_KEY>'`

Comment: Try Replacing : signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY)